# Android: How to search for nearby hotels using the Google Places API (Autocomplete)?

Tags: java, android, autocomplete, google-play-services, google-places-api

I'm making an app that is to be used in hotels, and I need the user to be able to tell the app what hotel they are at.

I am currently using Autocomplete and an AutocompleteFilter but I was wondering if I could filter the Autocomplete search results by place type... more specifically "lodging."

Here is what I currently have...

```
protected void PickPlace()
{

    Intent intent;
    AutocompleteFilter filter;

    try
    {
        filter = new AutocompleteFilter.Builder()
                .setTypeFilter(AutocompleteFilter.TYPE_FILTER_ADDRESS)
                .build();
        intent =  new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_FULLSCREEN)
                    .setFilter(filter)
                    .build(this);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE  );
    }
    catch(GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e)
    {
    // TODO
    }
    catch(GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e)
    {
        // TODO
    }

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if(requestCode == PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Place place = PlaceAutocomplete.getPlace(this, data);
            // TODO
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not married to Autocomplete or Google Places in general so if there's a better way altogether, I'm open to it.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, `lodging` type is only supported in [place search and addition](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/supported_types#table1) (you may opt to use this instead) but not in [place autocomplete requests](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/supported_types#table3).

You may want to [file a feature request](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/support#issue-tracker) and check [release notes](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/releases) for updates.